# Say what permissions a user has discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command in Discord.js that reads what permissions a user has. For example, you could do

> $permissions @user

and it would return with something like this:

> "Users permissions in this guild are: "

etc.. I am not sure if this is even possible, though if it is, some guidance on where i could start would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible because discord.js has a list of all the available permissions, so you loop on them and check if the user has the permission or if they don't have it.

```js
const Discord = require('discors.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('token');

client.on('message', (message) => {

    if (message.content === 'list-permissions') {
         // get the list of permissions
         const permissions = Object.keys(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS);
         message.channel.send(
              'Permissions of ' + message.author.username + '\n\n' +
              permissions.map((perm) => {
                    return message.member.hasPermission(perm) ? `${perm}: YES` : `${perm}: NO`
              }).join('\n');
        );
    }

});
```

This will return something like:

Permissions of Androz2091

MANAGE_MESSAGES: YES
BAN_MEMBERS: NO
KICK_MEMBERS: YES
etc...

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [GuildMembers#permissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions).

"The overall set of permissions for this member, taking only roles into account"